# how to use PARSENAME

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I get not the right result out of:

```
select parsename(replace('K.03.2_test', '_', '.' ), 2)
```

My result at the moment is:

```
2
```

...but I need all the string to the left from the underscore. So this is what I need:

```
K.03.2
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: ParseName is SQL Server not MySQL and there is no good reason to use it here.

Comment: I found nothing in the documentation. Is there another way to parse or split the string to receive the same result that I need?

Comment: This is how you could do it with `PARSENAME` : `REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE('K.03.2_test', '.', '|' ), '_', '.'), 2), '|', '.')` and this is why this function is not suitable for what you want to do here.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - As well as other undesirable characteristics such as returning `NULL` if one of the split components is longer than 128 characters and rejecting strings such as `]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the characters to the left of the underscore you can use

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN YourCol LIKE '%[_]%'
           THEN LEFT(YourCol, CHARINDEX('_', YourCol) - 1)
       END
FROM   YourTable
```

[`parsename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is designed to parse object identifiers not split arbitrary strings.